# Why toGray function is not showing output on device

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Why toGray function is not showing output on device , below is my code for converting image into grayscale , i change my code into function but its not showing output :

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int toGray(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra);

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_NativeActivity_CvNativeActivity_eqhist(JNIEnv* env, jobject,jint width, jint height, jintArray in, jintArray out)
   {
       jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
       jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

       Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
       Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);
       int conv;
       jint retVal;
       conv = toGray(mSrc, bgra);
       retVal = (jint)conv;
       return retVal;
       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);

   }
}

int toGray(Mat mSrc, Mat& bgra)
{
    Mat gray(mSrc.rows, mSrc.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(mSrc , gray , CV_BGRA2GRAY);
    cvtColor(gray , bgra , CV_GRAY2BGRA);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for the changes for _out to take effect you have to call `ReleaseIntArrayElements()`. But this is never executed because you return first.
Your code should be:

```
   env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
   env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);
   return retVal;
```

Also when your create the result

```
Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)_out);
```

that says bgra is 3 channels. But when you do `cvtColor(gray , bgra , CV_GRAY2BGRA);` in toGray() a 4 channel destination is needed and, since you provided a 3 channel Mat, bgra will be reallocated  (so your output color will not end up in the _out array).

Comment: Your answer is correct. The function is prematurely returning. And as far as toGray function is concerned, I think it's correct. Android bitmap supports RGBA. So a single channel output would not work. Hence gray to bgra conversion is required.

Comment: @B... oops sorry that is not `8UC3` that was `8UC4`